Trophy on user profile with no description
Today I noticed a trophy icon on my profile

I frankly don't know what it means or how I got it. Hovering over it doesn't give any info and inspecting the svg only gives me the name iconAchievements.
Does anyone know what this means and how you get it?

It's almost certainly a bug. That icon is marking the area where it would normally display some notable achievement, like #1 user this month. I would assume that, for users without a significant achievement to display, the icon itself would be hidden. This appears to be the first report of such a bug, either here or on MSE. But this is only speculation; I can't speak to what the true intention is.

@CodyGray I think that is by design if I remember correctly, my profile had the same empty icon before I got 200 rep. So even if you are not ranked it is still supposed to be there.

Achievements: you have no achievements :(

The fact that it's a long-standing bug doesn't, in my opinion, make it any less of a bug. I cannot think of any legitimate explanation for having a floating trophy/achievements icon in the profile when it does nothing and there are no achievements being displayed. If that's not a bug, I don't know what is. There shouldn't be UI elements that do absolutely nothing, and there shouldn't be UI elements that cause confusion. This breaks both rules. I used the weasel words "almost certainly" bc I've been surprised by "bugs by design" on numerous prior occasions, but those are still bugs IMO. @A-Tech

It is an artifact left over from the reputations league—a fun way to see how well you are doing compared to others on SO/SE.
The feature was essentially removed. Only the top 400 users are ranked (Which is about 0.0005% of the over 800 000 it had before). If you happen to become one of them, then you will see your rank/percentage next to that icon:


So, the fun is now over, except for the top 400 users. Well, at least everyone still gets a trophy.

@CodyGray So, you came back for your trophy?!! :) Jokes aside, it's really great to see you back. Amidst all the disastrous changes to the network, your return is definitely a good news!

"Participation trophies for Jedi, there are not." --Yoda.

It's become a participation trophy... Sigh. I'd rather have a cookie.

Carbs are the enemy, @Gimby . But realistically the poison is in the dosage, so safe cookie consumption will vary.

@user4581301 A cookie a day keeps the craving for pizza away.
